# How to load source file without header in IICS

Tags: informatica-cloud, iics

I want to load flat file which is ~ delimited but doesn't any header into Snowflake table using informatica cloud integration service.

[image: Source file image]

Just wanted to know how to add header to source file or any turn around in order to map fields in  fields mapping  option in target .Please find below screenshot. Not able to figure it out which field in source will be mapped in target table as source file does not have headers.

[image]

Comment: can you ask source person? Whoever is producing this file. We dont know your data/file content.

Comment: files are generated without headers at the source

Comment: can you pls chk source code ? whatever generating it must use a structure.

Answer (score 0):

In the format options of the source transformation you need to set "First Data Row"  property to 1.  See the below figure.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).